# Form field text color change on click or tab

Tags: jquery, css, forms, focus

I have a contact form on my site which have text that starts light grey, on click I have it set up so it changes colour but when I tab it doesn't. Is there away to detect if the user has used the tab button to get into the field instead of a click and cover this instance too.

HTML:

```
<input name="email" type="text" id="EmailField" class="extraFields" autocomplete="off">
```

jQuery:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.extraFields', function () {
     $(this).addClass('clickedField');
 });
```

CSS:

```
.extraFields{
     color:#cccccc;
}
.clickedField{
     color:#000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: you could try use `focus` instead of `click` (or as well as), hahaha just noticed you tagged this with focus too!

Comment: @davidkonrad tab key on the keyboard

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eFw6J/ ??

Answer (score 1):

Use a focus event instead of click:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.extraFields', function () {
    $(this).addClass('clickedField');
});
```

Comment: I would take both, click and focus

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the event listener is attached to the page's `body` element, so `$(this)` refers to it. To set the class on the field itself, use `e.target`:

```
// add class on focus
$('body').on('focus', '.extraFields', function (event) {
    $(event.target).addClass('clickedField');
});
// remove class on blur
$('body').on('blur', '.extraFields', function (event) {
    $(event.target).removeClass('clickedField');
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/event.target/